# Modern Opengl: Rotate a cuboid with pivot at one end of the cuboid

Tags: opengl, matrix, rotation, transformation, glm-math

[image]

So, I drew a Yellow cuboid using this

```cpp
glm::mat4 yellow_bone_obj_mat = m_bone_animation->get_yellow_mat();
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.program, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE,
                   glm::value_ptr(yellow_bone_obj_mat));
bone_obj->obj_color = m_bone_animation->colors[1];
draw_object(shader, *bone_obj);
```

witth the scale factor `{ 0.5f,4.0f,0.5f }` and position `{ 2.0f,3.0f,2.0f }`

I want my yellow cuboid to rotate 90 degrees towards right, while the end position of the yellow cuboid to stick the red cube

It should look like this

[image]

I tried

```cpp
m_yellow_mat = glm::translate(m_yellow_mat, glm::vec3(0.0, -0.5, 0.0)); //0.5f is just random number to check if pivot changed
m_yellow_mat = glm::rotate(m_yellow_mat, glm::radians(angle), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
m_yellow_mat = glm::translate(m_yellow_mat, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.5, 0.0));
```

Got this as output

[image]

Next i tried

```cpp
m_yellow_mat = glm::translate(m_yellow_mat, glm::vec3(0.0, -0.5, 0.0)); //0.5f is just random number to check if pivot changed
m_yellow_mat = glm::rotate(m_yellow_mat, glm::radians(angle), glm::vec3(1, 0, 0)); //changed axis
m_yellow_mat = glm::translate(m_yellow_mat, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.5, 0.0));
```

[image]

Got this as output. No matter what I do, the cuboid isn't falling at the right side. I am not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually do is to rotate a perfect cube and to scale the rotated cube. The cube is rotated, but the scale is applied after, so it appears to be always orientated to the same direction.

You've to scale the cube and then you've to rotated the cuboid:

```non
m_yellow_mat = translate(pivot) * rotate * translate(-pivot) * scale
```

Note, operations like [`rotate`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#gaee9e865eaa9776370996da2940873fd4), [`scale`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#ga05051adbee603fb3c5095d8cf5cc229b) and [`translate`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#ga1a4ecc4ad82652b8fb14dcb087879284) create a new matrix and multiply the current matrix by the new matrix. e.g:

```cpp
vec3 scale = glm::vec3(0.5f, 4.0f, 0.5f);
vec3 pivot = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);

m_yellow_mat = glm::mat4(1.0f);

m_yellow_mat = glm::translate(m_yellow_mat, pivot);
m_yellow_mat = glm::rotate(m_yellow_mat, glm::radians(angle), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
m_yellow_mat = glm::translate(m_yellow_mat, -pivot);
m_yellow_mat = glm::scale(m_yellow_mat, scale);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have few questions! What should be my initial scale? and how can I find the `y` value of pivot?